# Desinstalar carpetas del Postgre 9.5 en Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, windows10

He desinstalado el Postre 9.5 en Windows 10, pero no hay manera de eliminar las carpetas en el menu de windows, que evientemente están vacías. 
También la carpeta del Enterprise Apache se resiste a ser eliminado.

También las he eliminado de la dirección: ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/StartMenu/Programs

No ha funcionado y siguen las carpetas en el menu.

Mil gracias

Comment: puedes probar con ccleaner para limpiar el registro y verificar si tienen algunos componentes instalados

Comment: También he realizado lo que se aconseja en el servicio técnico de Windows sin funcionar:
[https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system]

Comment: @DavidSantos Creo que esa opción es de pago. La gratuita no me va solucionar el problema. no?

Comment: no la version gratuita tambien te puede ayudar

Comment: Entonces, lo probaremos y ya te contaré. Muchas gracias @DavidSantos